# ERROR TypeError: "x is null" on logout from the app

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

In my app. I am implementing authentication using this example [enter link description here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/15/angular-9-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example). I am getting an error ERROR TypeError: "x is null". when i implement logout function. What can be the problem and how can i resolve it. Please guide me.

I am using isCurrentUserAdmin method in multiple components to check if the user is admin or not.

authenticationService.ts

```
private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
public user: Observable<User>;

 isCurrentUserAdmin(): boolean {
    this.user.subscribe(x => this.currentUserRole = x.role);
    return this.user && this.currentUserRole === Role.admin;
  }


  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    this.deleteToken();
    this.userSubject.next(null);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

Comment: can you replace this.userSubject.next(null); with this.userSubject.next(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
isCurrentUserAdmin(): boolean {
    this.user.subscribe(x => this.currentUserRole = x ? x.role : null);
    return this.user && this.currentUserRole === Role.admin;
}
```

when you logout user becomes null
so x is null, so accessing x.role throws error

and @Gunnar B.'s solution, filtering it is not recommended
because this.currentUserRole have to be updated with User or else
when user logout they're still gonna have the role of the previous User.

Answer (score 0):

You send a `null` to the `userSubject` (which `user` will also get of course). Now, in `isCurrentUserAdmin` you try to access a property of `user`, but at that point `user === null` and it does not have the property (`role`) any more.

You'd need to filter null-users (and I'd actually not put the subscribe in that function since you will create a new subscription every time you call that function).

`this.user.pipe(filter(x => x !== null)).subscribe(x => this.currentUserRole = x.role);`

Now, as mentioned, put that subscribe somewhere else where it's only called once. And also make sure to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. In this case it might not be needed since the observable is in the same component and would get destroyed alongside (I think), but it is a good habit.

Edit:
Actually, you should probably unsubscribe when the user is set to null because technically you'd still have a role even though the user is null. (You prevent that in the return with `this.user`, but its still kind of wrong logic.)
When you subscribe when a user is set and unsubscribe when it is cleared, you'd probably not need the filter.

Edit2:
I'm not quite sure about performance (depending on how often you call the function), but you could also take the role directly from the user observable:

```
return this.user.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(x => x ? x.role : null);
```